# How does "Animated.createAnimatedComponent" work?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the Component ProgressBarAndroid, there are props indeterminable={Boolean} which show to a user an animation of what it's going on. I would like to do almost the same on ProgressViewIOS. So I tried to Animate it with Animated...

I saw on docs of Animated method called 'createAnimatedComponent' which they use to create Animated.View

I tried so to create another Animated (Native) Component but it doesn't work at all.
The animation should gradually raise fillValue to 20 % and continue with an original value from the media upload...

This is my Component

```
// ProgressBar.ios.js
// @flow
import { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Component from 'components/base/Component';
import { ProgressViewIOS, Animated } from 'react-native';

const AnimatedProgressViewIOS = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ProgressViewIOS);

class ProgressBarIOS extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    // Percentage (0 - 100)
    fill: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      fillValue: new Animated.Value(props.fill),
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.fill === 0) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.fillValue, { toValue: 0.2, duration: 500 }).start();
    } else if (nextProps.fill > 19) {
      this.state.fillValue.setValue(nextProps.fill / 100);
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.fill !== nextProps.fill;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AnimatedProgressViewIOS
        style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
        progress={this.state.fillValue} />
    );
  }

}

export default ProgressBarIOS;
```

EDIT: AnimatedComponent is used to modify style only. Props could be passed as animated value but remember it is not a number!

Comment: Does it render anything for you? For me when I wrap my component with animatable it just disappears.

Comment: I solved the problem, by wrapping the component I want to animate in an "<Animated.View>" tag, and then applying the animations to its styles. Not sure if this will help you though...

Answer (score 2):

`Animated.createAnimatedComponent` can animate a number of different properties, however only some properties are supported using the native driver, fortunately it appears `progress` on `ProgressViewIOS` is one of them.

Here is a [working implementation](https://snack.expo.dev/bSxbaTEXQ) of an animated `ProgressViewIOS`.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { ProgressViewIOS, Animated } from 'react-native';

const AnimatedProgressViewIOS = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(
  ProgressViewIOS
);

export default function App() {
  const value = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(value.current, {
        duration: 2000,
        toValue: 1,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      })
    ).start();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <AnimatedProgressViewIOS
          style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
          progress={value.current}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

It's worth noting that [ProgressViewIOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/progressviewios) is now deprecated, but building your own progress view is very straight forward and requires just two `View`s with simple styling like this ([expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/l18mMI33H)):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(() => Math.random());

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <AnimatedProgressView progress={progress} />
        <Text style={{padding: 20, textAlign: 'center'}}>{Math.round(progress * 100)}%</Text>
        <Button title="Animate" onPress={() => setProgress(Math.random())} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function AnimatedProgressView({ progress, style }) {
  const value = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Animated.spring(value.current, { toValue: progress }).start();
  }, [progress]);

  return (
    <View
      style={[styles.track, style]}
      onLayout={(event) => setWidth(event.nativeEvent.layout.width)}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.fill,
          {
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: value.current.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [-width, 0],
                  overflow: 'clamp',
                }),
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  track: {
    minHeight: 4,
    borderRadius: 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
  },
  fill: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});
```